# Do you know any application that helps to keep a inventory of dependency beetween aplications and servers?

Tags: infrastructure

with the grow of the number of servers and applications in our environment, we are facing a problem when we need to reboot some server and do it, thinking that is safe, and then we realise that some forgotten application, had a weird dependency to the server that no one remembered.

So,to prevent this situation, we are looking for some software, that does something like add all apps and its dependencies , so you can later select one app and see whom its dependencies are(software or servers), or select one server and see the apps are you breaking if you reboot it.

I had searched internet and didn't found anything like that, so, did you solved this problem in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This software category is called Configuration management database CMDB in ITIL framework terminology.

There are several software vendor providing CMDB software:

- HP UCMDB http://www8.hp.com/h20195/V2/GetPDF.aspx/4AA1-6156ENW.pdf
- OneCMDB http://www.onecmdb.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
- and so more search CMDB in google

In my previous experiences, I used HP UCMDB and it allows to resolve the problem described in your answer.
This type of software must be contain updated information about apps/server dependencies in order to be useful; in a complex environment with several systems this can be a challenge.